# Use grep to find text, if found in file echo another string inside that file

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I am wondering if there is a one liner for doing what I am looking for, or if I have to write a bash script. What I am looking to do is search recursively in a directory, if the string I am looking for is found then search that same file for another string and print it to the screen. So in this example I want to find out if the score of the "X-Spam-Status" header is between a range in the email, if it is, print out the sender or the subject header in that email.

Example:

The command I am using is:

```
grep 'X-Spam-Status: .* score=[5-9]\.' /var/email/example.com/example/cur/* | wc -l
```

Here is the header that I need to locate this information in:

```
X-Spam-Status: No, score=6.5 required=5.0 tests=HTML_MESSAGE,
        RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE,T_DKIM_INVALID,URIBL_BLOCKED autolearn=ham version=3.3.2
```

If grep finds a match in the header above, find and echo this header from the same email:

```
From: "From the Desk of Allen Watson" <FromtheDeskofAllenWatson@emadest.eu>
Subject: Don't Live in Fear of Loud Noises
```

It can be either the subject or the from. It does not need to be both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution first uses a find, which has a file filter.
To make sure, spaces in filenames are correctly handled, the switch **-print0** is used to create a list of null terminated filenames.

This list is used by xargs to pass the arguments to the grep command, which outputs a null terminated line too. You can use as many xargs grep combinations as you like.

The last command in the pipe is without the **-Z**, if you want to read the output. In our case I just used a `head -2` to output the first two lines of the file.

```
function grep2strings_recursive() {
    if [ '0' = "$#" ]; then
        echo "Usage: $FUNCNAME <dir> <string1> <string2>"
        return
    fi
    find "$1" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -lZ "$2" | xargs -0 grep -lZ "$3" | xargs -0 head -2
}

grep2strings_recursive '/var/email/example.com/example/cur'  'X-Spam-Status: .* score=[5-9]\.' 'From'
```

It is important to use the null output terminators (**-print0 and -Z**) and the null input terminators (**-0**) to ensure correct behaviour in case of space/tab/newlines characters in filenames.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I was able to create it as a one liner by just adding everything to the `find` command after the `if` statement. The output is formatted nicely also. Thanks. One more thing I have played around trying to get the value of "X-Spam-Status" to be echoed instead of the file name. How do I do this? The only information I care to see is the `Score` value and the `From` Value

Comment: instead of `head -2` just use `egrep -h '^(From|X-Spam-Status)'` - if this is not what you expect, please post an example output.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
find /path/to/files -type f | xargs -i grep "searchterm" {} | grep -o "othersearchterm"
```

i.e.

```
find /path/to/files -type f | xargs -i grep "X-Spam-Status" {} | egrep -o '(From|Subject).*'
```

Comment: This did not work without modifications. I ended up getting it to work as a one liner by following the answer from `lx42.de` and basically stripping it down to just the `find` command after the `if` statement.